# How to change the Bootstrap accordion panel heading/title background color when the accordion collapses and is open

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is the code which needs the background color change when the accordion collapses and is open:
http://www.bootply.com/cherylbbb/COm6fikZKx

How can I change the css to style the background color change?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it via CSS playing with the `panel-heading` and `collapsed` classes. Par example append these lines to your css:

```
/* set panel-heading paddings to a instead of h3 */    
.panel-heading { padding: 0 }
.panel-heading h3 { background: #bbf; }
.panel-heading a { padding: 10px 15px; }

/* change color of collapsed class */
.collapsed { background: #fbb; }

/* reposition the left arrows */
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle.collapsed:after { top: 10px; }
.panel-heading .accordion-toggle:after { top: 10px; }
```

See how [your demo looks like with the changes](http://www.bootply.com/wyEOyFg40X)

Comment: Thank you very much! @Geo Halkiadakis